# WPF Stop Storyboard on Visibility Changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, visibility, storyboard

I have a UserControl with a story board and I want to stop the animation when the control's Visibility changes.

I created a Trigger to pause the animation and start it depending on the state, but I keep getting an ArgumentException.

Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ProgressAnimation_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ProgressAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
        <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ProgressAnimation_BeginStoryboard" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible">
        <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ProgressAnimation_BeginStoryboard" />
    </Trigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

and here is the Exception:

> The value "System.Windows.Media.Animation.PauseStoryboard" is not of type "System.Windows.SetterBase" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
>   Parameter name: value

How would I do this in XAML ?

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 18):

You may do it using a control template:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    ... Control stuff here

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimationStoryboard}" x:Name="AnimationBeginStoryboard"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AnimationBeginStoryboard"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for the question, because use this way can't pause and resume the animation.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this [sample from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d2517850-81cc-4d22-be7d-cad522540ad2):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <StackPanel>
  <Rectangle Name="TargetRect" Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Blue"/>
  <Button Name="Begin">BeginStoryboard</Button>
  <Button Name="Pause">PauseStoryboard</Button>
  <Button Name="Resume">ResumeStoryboard</Button>
  <StackPanel.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger SourceName="Begin" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <BeginStoryboard Name="ColorStoryboard">
     <Storyboard TargetName="TargetRect">
      <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
     </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger SourceName="Pause" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ColorStoryboard"/>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger SourceName="Resume" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ColorStoryboard"/>
   </EventTrigger>
  </StackPanel.Triggers>
 </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The only difference I can see is that they are using `EventTrigger` here, but it should behave the same, at least in my experience.

Comment: That won't work because a UserControl can only contain EventTriggers while I need a <Trigger>.