# Stop a Storyboard from another Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have a Storyboard in the MainWindow as follow :

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonDown1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"  RepeatBehavior="Forever" DecelerationRatio="1" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

in the same window i have a button to call this StoryBoard and in the same time to open a new Window as follows :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb= this.Resources["OnMouseLeftButtonDown2"] as Storyboard;
                if (sb != null)
                    sb.Begin(this);
                Window2 win = new Window2();
                win.Show();
    }
```

Now when it shows the Window2 i want stop the storyboard["OnMouseLeftButtonDown2"] with a button control ,do you have any suggestion how work out this step?

Tahnsk so much for your attention,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you want to stop the Storyboard from your new Window - right?
I would suggest some thing like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb= this.Resources["OnMouseLeftButtonDown2"] as Storyboard;
                if (sb != null)
                    sb.Begin(this);
                Window2 win = new Window2();
                win.StopStoryboardAction = () => sb.Stop();
                win.Show();
    }
```

Just give your new Window a public Property for the Action:

```
public Action StopStoryboardAction { get; set; }
```

And inside your new window just call

```
if (StopStoryboardAction != null) StopStoryboardAction();
```

This way you get some fewer dependencies.

PS:

- I think you can also write `win.StopStoryboardAction = sb.Stop`
- maybe you have to get the current dispatcher in the closure but I don't think so

Comment: ,Hi ,i tried your suggestion but in the second Window(Window2) when i click the button to stop the storyboard ,doesn't happen anything.Thansk so much

Comment: Hi, you have to check a few things: 1) do you call the StopStoryboardAction in you Button-Click event 2) can you debug and be sure that the action is called 3) does the storyboard stop when you call stop in window 1?

Comment: ,yes i check out well now it is right,i was a bit tired :D.THanks so much for our help.

Answer (score 0):

Related posts - [xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009880/wpf-stop-storyboard-on-visibility-changed) and [code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623601/stop-wpf-animation-storyboard-begin-in-xaml-but-stopping-it-in-codebehind)

```
StoryBoard board = (StoryBoard)this.FindResource("OnMouseLeftButtonDown2"); 
board.stop();
```