# ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState returns false in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, visualstatemanager

I have a custom control whose Animation I want to control.  I attempt to update this using `VisualStateManager.GoToState` but it always returns `false` in Silverlight and the animation never starts. This works perfectly in WPF though with the same XAML.

The Silverlight code

```
//to start
retval = ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.canvasParent, "WorkingState", true);
```

The WPF code

```
retval = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.canvasParent, "WorkingState", true);
```

XAML (common):

```
<Style TargetType="local:WaitSpinner">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WaitSpinner">
                <Viewbox Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                    <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="CanvasParent" Width="120" Height="120">
                        <!-- other awesomeness -->

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Working">
                                <VisualState x:Name="WorkingState">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Stop"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put  `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` on the first `ControlTemplate` child :

```
<Style TargetType="local:WaitSpinner">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WaitSpinner">
                <Viewbox Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Working">
                            <VisualState x:Name="WorkingState">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                    From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Stop"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <!-- ................. -->
```

**Edit :** (I full response with your comment) Use `VisualStateManager` `GotoState` method with `this` :

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "WorkingState", true);
```

Comment: That unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Correction: When using `VisualStateManager.GotoState` with `this` it works! I only used the extended one because this originall didnt work, thanks

Comment: Yep, I had not seen the `this.canvasParent` and `GoToElementState` sorry... I added it to my answer...